# How to install ruby and bundler with dockerfile?

Tags: ruby, docker, bundler, dockerfile, root

New to ruby and bundler here.
I am installing them in a docker image with this docker file:

```
FROM alpine:3.5

# Install Ruby, Ruby Bundler and other ruby dependencies

RUN apk add --update \
      ruby ruby-bigdecimal ruby-bundler \
      ca-certificates libressl \
      libressl-dev build-base ruby-dev \
      ruby-rdoc ruby-io-console ruby-irb; \
\
    && bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries; \
    && bundle config git.allow_insecure true; \
\
    && gem install json foreman --no-rdoc --no-ri; \
    && gem cleanup; \
    && rm -rf /usr/lib/ruby/gems/*/cache/*; \
    && apk del libressl-dev build-base ruby-dev; \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* /tmp;

CMD ["bundle"]
```

When I run do a docker run I get:

```
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed,
and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all
non-root users on this machine.
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

How do I resolve this? I just want to install ruby and ruby-bundle and be done with this ...

Comment: are there non-root users of the machine?

Comment: this is a docker container so I don't think so.

Comment: i don't either. why not just ignore the warning?

Comment: The full log that comes from that container is : Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Could not locate Gemfile. Do you know anything about this "Could not locate Gemfile" ?

Comment: running bundle requires a gemfile in the directory, either there is no gemfile, or you are in the wrong directory

Comment: What can I do to work with this type of failure? ... I am not deploying any ruby app I just want ruby and bundler installed as part of this docker image and that's it ...

Answer (score 4):

There are pre built [ruby](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/) images (e.g [Alpine 3.11 Ruby 2.7](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/a564feaaee4c8647c299ab11d41498468bb9af7b/2.7/alpine3.11/Dockerfile)) that include `bundler`. It's easier to start with them as they generally use the current "best practices" to build.

Notice that they set the [`BUNDLE_SILENCE_ROOT_WARNING`](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/a564feaaee4c8647c299ab11d41498468bb9af7b/2.7/alpine3.11/Dockerfile#L122) environment variable with [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) directive in the image build to remove that `root` warning.

You normally wouldn't run `bundler` as the [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) for a container either, you might run `bundler` during a [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) image build step though.

Running containers as non-root users is not a bad idea in any case. Use the [`USER`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) directive to change that.

```
FROM ruby:2.7
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/
RUN set -uex; \
    bundle install; \
    adduser -D rubyapp; \
    mkdir -p /app/data; \
    chown rubyapp /app/data
USER rubyapp
CMD [ "ruby", "whatever.rb" ]
```

Comment: I decided to build this container starting from an ubuntu image. Actually now I am only dealing with "Could not locate Gemfile"

Comment: The [`2.4-stretch`](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/9390129c08cc19668fc482edfd7d7c5a890a80eb/2.4/stretch/Dockerfile) image will be pretty close to Ubuntu. The `Gemfile` and your app should be `COPY`d or `ADD`ed to the image before you run `bundle`